# Creating daily grid from table using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, time-series

I´m trying to create a daily grid file for precipitation from a xlx table table that has X, Y, P1, P2,..., P365 columns and n gauges rows.  I´m new in ModelBuilder but it seems this may be the best way for somebody that has no programming.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your starting model could include an Excel To Table tool.

Comment: After converting to a table look into the make XY event layer tool.